# call tearDown() in setUp()?

Tags: python, unit-testing

In a `TestCase` in `setUp()` I want to be sure that the data of the database is in a known state.

Since I don't know if an other Test has left some data around, I started to delete old stuff.

Now I discovered that I can use less code if I call `tearDown()` in the first line of `setUp()`.

Is this a common pattern? Or is there a better solution?

**Update**

I know how `tearDown()` gets called (always after the test).

Comment: Why not tearDown in the test itself?

Comment: for test in tests: setUp -> test -> tearDown. You do not need to call teardown in setup. Teardown is always called. it is in a finally statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment on your post, tearDown will always be run after a test run, whether the run is successful or not. If you are concerned that your database might be getting data added to it from somewhere between test runs, then you could extrapolate out your db clean code and call it at the beginning of setUp as well:

```
class Test(unittest.testcase):
    def cleanDB(self):
        """db cleaning code goes here"""
    def setUp(self):
        self.cleanDB()
        # Rest of setup code
    def tearDown(self):
        # tearDown code
        self.cleanDB()
```